# What is difference between "node --prof" and using node-profiler

Tags: node.js, profiling, v8

I'm trying to profile node 0.10.33, the case requires profiler to be activated in code. so --prof is not suits.

v8tools based profilers returns profile logs in memory using json tree, which is not suits for any visualization tool.

Main problem using node-profiler is logs received by it is not readable by any tool: nprof, chrome://tracing/ etc. For example nprof gives lots of "Code move event for unknown code" errors and

```
 [Unknown]:
 ticks  total  nonlib   name
 146518   98.8%
```

as result.

The same time using just --prof gives valid logs.

As i see it node-profiler just calls to v8 built-in profiler resuming it, for thus we calls node with "--prof", "--prof_lazy", "--log" parameters. So logs must be identical.

Where im wrong?